# Is this integral formula valid

Tags: calculus, integration

So I was playing with the Quotient rule for derivatives and I found $$\int \frac{du}{v}=\frac{u}{v}+\int \frac{u \cdot dv}{v^2}$$ Is this formula valid and does it help to integrate fractions?

Comment: Yes, it's integration by parts. It can help or not, depending on the functions $u$ and $v$.

Comment: You could improve the quality of this post by showing your derivation. That way if it were wrong your specific error could be pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a valid formula based on the quotient, and has a similar role to integration by parts (which corresponds to the product rule). In fact, just as the quotient rule can be deduced quickly from the product and the chain rule, we can deduce this formula from integrating by parts:

$$\int \frac 1 v \, du = \frac 1 v \cdot u - \int u d \frac 1 v = \frac u v - \int -u \frac{dv}{v^2}$$

as desired.

So it's pretty much exactly as useful as integration by parts is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the integral is valid.

$$\int \frac{du}{v}=\frac{u}{v}+\int \frac{u \cdot dv}{v^2}$$

This is a special case of integration by  parts which is 
$$\int udv=uv-\int vdu $$

Integration by parts is a valid and very useful method of interating a product.

What you have done is coming up with a formula which integrates the quotients.

Just as the integration by parts which is not always the key to solve integrals, your formula may or may not be applicable for all quotients.